# For loop - PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql

i'm trying to figure out how to create a for loop to bring up the first 10 entries.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to SQL';
}

$sql = "SELECT id, user_id, post_date, in_reply_to, texts FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


?>
```

Everything works up to that point, as i tried a bunch of different things and got no where.

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: What output are you expecting VS what you're getting? What's your specific question?

Comment: just the mysqli_query returning a boolean.

i need to display the first 10 records.

Comment: Probably try reading a tutorial. E.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_select_query.htm) is an example you could adapt.

Comment: If `mysqli_query` returned a boolean, it must have been `false`, indicating an error with your query. Try printing `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almsot certainly don't want a loop for this.  A PHP loop getting the top 10 results would involve a mysql qyuery with a top 1 and keeping track of the results for the next query.  Easier to just have a query for the top 10.  In mysql, the top X is obtained using `order by z limit X;`.